# Delete link for documents in Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

In the Sharepoint Document Library web part, is there a way to have a delete link for each of the files listed?

In the regular view of a document library you have a dropdown available when you hover over a filename, but there doesn't appear to be any option to delete a file in the web part.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: @Ashish - I have now retagged with 2007, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have proper permissions to delete the document. Usuallay if you have permission then you will see "Delete" option in the drop down menu.

Goto Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Modify All Site Settings -? Advanced Permissions

Click the appropriate group and make sure the user has permission to delete documents.

Comment: As mentioned in my question. The option to delete is not available in the web part. Although it is available in the standard Document Library view.

Comment: Oh okay!! then "Modify" the webpart and change its view to "All Documents" and it will be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, new to this and have some misunderstandings.